# Explanation on how to use the spin tool

Tags: modeling, mesh, interface, edit-mode

As displayed below is an image of a mug mesh I was creating for an exercise for this beginner tutorial I am currently on and the spin tool is just not doing the handle justice as its bent to one side. I really want to understand it better.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually I prefer to use the Spin tool by search for the old school modifier, rather than the new gizmo. I feel it's alot easier to wrap your head around. You can find that by pushing `F3` and typing spin.

[image]

I like to keep it set to a hotkey, then it's even easier.

You want to switch to an orthographic view that is perpendicular with the plane you want to spin the vertices on.

So in your screenshot you would want to be in what looks like "Right" or maybe "Left" view.

[image]

You'll also want to make sure the face that you're extruding is aligned parallel to you camera view before you use the spin tool. So if you're spinning a face on a cylinder, you might need to rotate the whole mesh by (360 / <number_of_sides>) / 2.

So on a 24-sided cylinder you would rotate it 7.5 degrees.

Before:
[image]

After:

[image]

This is part of what's causing you problems in this screenshot.

[image]

You'll also want to preemptively set the 3D cursor to the center of  where you want the center of the spin operation to be. This is where it will be set to by default once you run the operator.

Once you've got all this set up you run the operator and mess with these settings to get the effect you want.

[image]

It seems like alot but all told it's pretty simple. Once you get the hang of it it'll just go like this:

[image]

ezpz